# Microsoft Exchange 2007/2010 send SOAP request on an event?

Tags: c#, soap, exchange-server, exchange-server-2007

is it possible for exchange server to send SOAP request (acts like a client) when on a new event?

like calendar or contact adding/editing/deleting ?

we have a web based system that works when people create event and it sends it to exchange, but is it possible to have exchange sends to our system (SOAP or any other technology) when people create event with outlook (exchange)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what route you took to solve your problem but here is what I did to have our Exchange server send us notification on new emails. You can use Microsoft's official Exchange Web Service (EWS) to subscribe to streaming notifications . In your case you would want to subscribe to `WellKnownFolderName.Calendar` and `WellKnownFolderName.Contacts`.

See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2010/12/22/working-with-streaming-notifications-by-using-the-ews-managed-api.aspx).